# SharePoint Customized QA Admin post Q and users post answer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

SharePoint has a great customized communities platform built into 2013, but in this case I need a QA forum where the Admin managers can post questions and then individual end users can post free form answers. Similar to a survey, but allows for interaction like a message board after the question is posted. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives I would use would be to use the discussion board as you can use the check box indicating that the thread or post is a question that needs an answer. One of the replies can then be selected as the 'best answer'. (Item level permissions would manage who can edit what)

A blog type of site might also work for this if you customize the permissions for the blog posts and comments lists to separate the questions and replies / answers.

Hope this helps generate some ideas, give them a try to see what best fits your requirements. I think the community site template you started with is the closest thing to a 'forum' type of site.